# How to configure https for an apache redirecting to tomcat via mod_proxy connector (ajp)

Tags: apache, tomcat, https, mod-proxy, ajp

I have an apache server on an linux system (on amazon aws), running with https. I also have an tomcat on it. I want to use the apache as a front door to the tomcat. I enabled the mod_proxy module for the apache and the redirection to the tomcat works fine and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName my.domain.com

   #Log
   ErrorLog /var/log/ajp.error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/ajp.log combined

   #AJP configuration
   <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyRequests Off

   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

 </VirtualHost>
```

I added this lines at the bottom of my file httpd.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d folder.

But if I add another VirtualHost in the httpd.conf file to redirect to https, the redirection to https works but the apache Test page will be shown, not the tomcat page. If I remove this redirection VirtualHost the apache tomcat page will be shown. I also enabled the mod_rewrite module. The https stuff I configured in ssl.conf (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf) and it works fine. There I setup the ssl certificates and if the client make an request with an known https certificate the server will answer the request. Else not.

The VirtualHost for the https redirection I added to the httpd.conf looks like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName my.domain.com
         RewriteEngine on
         ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
         RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
    </VirtualHost>
```

Can you please help me? What I am doing wrong here? Should I make changes in the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file? I am very

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now I got the solution for that problem. I wrote this lines at the bottom of the /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf, before VirtualHost ends:

```
#Log
ErrorLog /var/log/ajp.error.log
CustomLog /var/log/ajp.log combined

#AJP configuration
<Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

Answer (score 0):

The following block

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName my.domain.com
  # [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

is like saying "this block will handle *everything* for http://my.domain.com". You can't add an other one with the same port/ServerName: they won't merge, one will shadow the other.

If the https part already works and you want to redirect all the http traffic to https, you can completely comment/remove the first `<VirtualHost *:80>` block (with the proxy). The proxy rules in your `<VirtualHost *:443>` will handle everything (assuming the https part works).

If you want to redirect only parts to https (not your question but that should help you understand it), you should put the `RewriteEngine` / `ReWriteCond` / `RewriteRule` directives *inside* the existing virtualhost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I removed the second VirtualHost and I change the first Virtual Host with the ajp and the proxy to <VirtualHost *:443>. I redirects to https, but it does not direct to the tomcat page. I see the apache test page. I also tried to add the rewrite rules from the second VirtualHost in the first one, but the behaviour is the same. I see the apache test page, not the tomcat start page. How can I handle this? What I am doing wrong?